# I cannot make the react app show the right modal I want it to show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am making the same steps as the tutorial but I'm not getting the same results and I don't know why,when I don't put any value in the input it should show a message in the modal,but instead it shows an error that I put there just in case I forgot and put for the useReducer() a type of action that doesn't exist in my app,if anyone could answer I would be highly thankful,and thank you if you're still reading this

```
import Modal from './Modal';
import { data } from '../../../data';
import { findAllByTitle } from '@testing-library/react';
// reducer function
const reducer=(state,action)=>{
  if(action.type==='ADD_ITEM'){
    const newPeople=[...state.people,action.payload]
    return {...state,
      people:newPeople,
      isModalOpen:true,
      modalContent:'item added'};
  }
  if(action.type==='NO_VALUE'){
    return {...state,
      isModalOpen:true,
      modalContent:'please enter a value'};
  }
  if(action.type==='CLOSE_MODAL'){
    return {...state,
      isModalOpen:false};
  }
  if(action.type==='REMOVE_ITEM'){
    const newPeople=state.people.filter((person)=>person.id!==action.payload)
    return {...state,
      people:newPeople};
  }
  throw new Error('no matching action type')
}
const defaultState={
  people:[],
  isModalOpen:false,
  modalContent:''
}
const Index = () => {
  const [name,setName]=useState('')
  const [state,dispatch]=useReducer(reducer,defaultState)
  const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(name){
      const newItem={
        id:new Date().getTime().toString()
        ,name
      }
      dispatch({type:'ADD_ITEM',payload:newItem})
      setName('')
    } 
    else{
      dispatch('NO_VALUE');
    }
  }
  const closeModal=()=>{
    dispatch({type:'CLOSE_MODAL'});
  }
  return (<>
  {state.isModalOpen && <Modal closeModal={closeModal} modalContent={state.modalContent}/>}
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='form'>
     <div>
       <input type="text" 
       value={name} 
       onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} />
     </div>
     <button type="submit">add</button>
  </form>
   {state.people.map((person)=>{
      return (<div key={person.id} className='item'>
        <h4>{person.name}</h4>
        <button 
        onClick={()=>dispatch({type:'REMOVE_ITEM',payload:person.id})}>
        remove</button>
      </div>)
    })}
  
  
  </>)
  }
  

export default Index;



`in another file`

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Modal = ({modalContent,closeModal}) => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>closeModal(),3000)
  })
  return <div className='modal'>
       <p>{modalContent}</p>
  </div>;
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: at the begininning you need to import it from react library.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`import React, { useReducer } from 'React';`

You need to import it and put this before `modal` import

Comment: oh,simple errors make a huge difference hahahaha,thanks!

Comment: nice...that's true...please kindly accept and upvote the answer if it solve your issue

Comment: oh ok,but everytime I try to do this says "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."